# AudioKit File Normalization

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm trying to normalize audio file after record to make it louder or vice versa, but i'm getting error `WARNING AKAudioFile: cannot normalize a silent file`

I have checked recordered `audioFile.maxLevel` and it was `1.17549e-38`, minimum float.

I'm using official [Recorder example](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/tree/master/Examples/iOS/Recorder), and to normalize after record i added this code:

```
let norm = try player.audioFile.normalized(newMaxLevel: -4.0);
```

What I'm doing wrong? Why maxLevel invalid? Record is loud enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than use the internal audio file of the player, make a new instance like so:

```
if let file = try? AKAudioFile(forReading: url) {
    if let normalizedFile = try? file.normalized(newMaxLevel: -4) {
        Swift.print("Normalized file sucess: \(normalizedFile.maxLevel)")
    }
}
```

I can add a normalize func to the AKAudioPlayer so that it's available for playback. Essentially, the player just uses the AKAudioFile for initialization, and all subsequent operations happen in a buffer.

Comment: Wow! it's working! Thank you! But what strange, after normalization newMaxLevel is -2.42144, but i execute normalize function with -4, hmm)

Comment: I'll look into that